# Google Maps operation confusing me in Android

Tags: android, if-statement, google-maps-android-api-2

I have this seemingly simple class in my app. All it does it add a circle to the `mapView` at my `Location` with the circle color depending on the `CDMA signal Strength` at the location. Or that's what it's supposed to do. 
The app works fine if I only ask for one circle and the location with the cdma signal but it doesn't work in the if Statement format, even if there is only one `else if` present. My question is why and if It has anything to do with how many times maps can be called at once. And If anyone knows a workaround, it would help a lot.

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
    int cdmaSignal;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    BroadcastReceiver br;



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(br == null){
            br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent z) {


                    shoveItThrough((int) z.getExtras().get("cell signal cdma"),
                            (double) z.getExtras().get("latitude"), (double) z.getExtras().get("longitude"));
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))      // Sets the center of the map to location user
                            .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
                            .bearing(0)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                            .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                            .build();
                    //
                    //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));


                    /*mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                            .center(new LatLng(latitude,longitude)).radius(80).strokeColor(Color.rgb(255,0,0)).fillColor(Color.rgb((255,0,0)));*/
                    //LatLng home = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);




                    //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(home));
                    if(cdmaSignal<=-120 && cdmaSignal>-100){
                        mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                                .center(new LatLng(latitude,longitude)).radius(80).strokeColor(Color.rgb(255,0,0)).fillColor(Color.rgb(255,0,0)));
                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                        /*LatLng home = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(home));
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(home));*/
                    } else if(cdmaSignal<=-100 && cdmaSignal>-80){
                        mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                                .center(new LatLng(latitude,longitude)).radius(80).strokeColor(Color.rgb(255,98,12)).fillColor(Color.rgb(255,98,12)));
                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                        /*LatLng home = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(home));
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(home));*/
                    } else if(cdmaSignal<=-80 && cdmaSignal>-60){
                        mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                                .center(new LatLng(latitude,longitude)).radius(80).strokeColor(Color.rgb(255,181,12)).fillColor(Color.rgb(255,181,12)));

                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                        /*LatLng home = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(home));
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(home));*/
                    } else if(cdmaSignal<=-60 && cdmaSignal>-40){
                        mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                                .center(new LatLng(latitude,longitude)).radius(80).strokeColor(Color.rgb(211,255,0)).fillColor(Color.rgb(211,255,0)));
                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                        /*LatLng home = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(home));
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(home));*/
                    } else if(cdmaSignal<=-40 && cdmaSignal>-20){
                        mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                                .center(new LatLng(latitude,longitude)).radius(80).strokeColor(Color.rgb(164,255,0)).fillColor(Color.rgb(164,255,0)));
                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                        /*LatLng home = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(home));
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(home));*/
                    } else if(cdmaSignal<=-20 && cdmaSignal>-0){

                        mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                                .center(new LatLng(latitude,longitude)).radius(80).strokeColor(Color.rgb(0,255,0)).fillColor(Color.rgb(0,255,0)));
                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                        /*LatLng home = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(home));
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(home));*/
                    }


                }
            };
        }
        registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter("location_update"));

    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(br != null){
            unregisterReceiver(br);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
    }

    public void shoveItThrough(int c, double la, double lo){
        cdmaSignal = c;
        latitude = la;
        longitude = lo;


    }



}
```

Comment: You need to rethink the logic in all of your `if` statements. `if(cdmaSignal<=-120 && cdmaSignal>-100)` - Those are negative numbers. A number cannot be less than or equal to -120 _and_ greater than -100.

Comment: @MikeM. I am grateful and completely embarrassed. Thank you

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks lol, but this might teach someone one day. Another exhausted newbie out there.